# IPsec/Openswan log user name and public IP

Tags: linux, vpn, ipsec

I'm attempting to have a slightly more organized openswan logging system and I think I've over thought it. I'm really just trying to save username and public IPs. This is what I so far but it's still returning more data than I need and I'd rather not build a complicated parser. I imagine there has got to be a way to get just this info without getting to overly complicated.

```
ipsec auto --status | grep 'STATE_MAIN_R3' > /home/ipsec.log
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

providing which protocol you're using for authentication will help

Since you mentioned "username and public IPs" I'm guessing you're doing some kind of road worrier IPSec connection. if this is true then with openswan it is usually L2TP/IPSec. In this case you will not see the userid in the "ipsec auto --status" since the user authentication is done by the L2TP/PPP stack. if you're using xl2tpd then it usually logs into /var/log/syslog

Hope this is helpful